# How to stack machine learning models in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, ensemble-learning

I am new to machine learning and R.

I know that there is an R package called [caretEnsemble](http://github.com/zachmayer/caretEnsemble), which could conveniently stack the models in R. However, this package looks has [some problems when deals with multi-classes classification tasks](http://github.com/zachmayer/caretEnsemble/issues/8).

Temporarily, I wrote some codes to try to stack the models manually and here is the example I worked on:

```
    library(caret)
    set.seed(123)
    library(AppliedPredictiveModeling)
    data(AlzheimerDisease)
    adData = data.frame(diagnosis, predictors)
    inTrain = createDataPartition(adData$diagnosis, p = 3 / 4)[[1]]
    training = adData[inTrain,]
    testing = adData[-inTrain,]

    set.seed(62433)
    modelFitRF <- train(diagnosis ~ ., data = training, method = "rf")
    modelFitGBM <- train(diagnosis ~ ., data = training, method = "gbm",verbose=F)
    modelFitLDA <- train(diagnosis ~ ., data = training, method = "lda")

    predRF <- predict(modelFitRF,newdata=testing)
    predGBM <- predict(modelFitGBM, newdata = testing)
    prefLDA <- predict(modelFitLDA, newdata = testing)

    confusionMatrix(predRF, testing$diagnosis)$overall[1]
    #Accuracy 
    #0.7682927 

    confusionMatrix(predGBM, testing$diagnosis)$overall[1]
    #Accuracy 
    #0.7926829 

    confusionMatrix(prefLDA, testing$diagnosis)$overall[1]
    #Accuracy 
    #0.7682927
```

Now I've got three models: `modelFitRF`, `modelFitGBM` and `modelFitLDA`, and three predicted vectors corresponding to such three models based on the `test set`.

Then I will create a data frame to contain these predicted vectors and the original dependent variable in the `test set`:

```
   predDF <- data.frame(predRF, predGBM, prefLDA, diagnosis = testing$diagnosis, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

And then, I just used such data frame as a new `train set` to create a stacked model:

```
   modelStack <- train(diagnosis ~ ., data = predDF, method = "rf")
   combPred <- predict(modelStack, predDF)
   confusionMatrix(combPred, testing$diagnosis)$overall[1] 
   #Accuracy 
   #0.804878
```

Considering that stacking models usually should improve the accuracy of the predictions, I'de like to believe this might be a right to stack the models. However, I also doubt that here I used the `predDF` which is created by the predictions from three models with the `test set`.

I am not sure **whether I should use the results from the `test set` and then apply them back to the `test set` to get final predictions**? 
(I am referring to this block below:)

```
   predDF <- data.frame(predRF, predGBM, prefLDA, diagnosis = testing$diagnosis, stringsAsFactors = F)
   modelStack <- train(diagnosis ~ ., data = predDF, method = "rf")
   combPred <- predict(modelStack, predDF)
   confusionMatrix(combPred, testing$diagnosis)$overall[1]
```

Comment: You can divide predDF into a validation set (which you do stacking on) and the final test set (which you do out-of-sample prediction on). Don't stack on the whole predDF as your model should not be dependent on the final test set in any way.

Comment: Hi @raymkchow, so you mean: I could separate the predDF into validation and test sets, and apply the three models and the stacked model on the validation set to see the results and compare with such results to find the best model. Next, I could apply that best model to the test set to do out-of-sample prediction right?

Comment: Yes you are right. We can either choose the best models, or combine these three models (base models) into a better model.